# Adding facts to a correct answer in a python quiz

Tags: python

I am creating a multiple choice quiz in python and I want to display a fact on the subject of the question when a user answers it correctly along with the score. Each question has a fact.  I have a dictionary for the answers and a dictionary for the facts.  I'm unsure of how to display properly insert that into the loop.

example:

1. Who directed Underworld, Underworld Evolution?

   a. Louis Leteriere
   b. Len Wiseman
   c. Martin Campbell
   d. James Wan

after the user enters their answer. I would like to display a fact (if the answer is correct), such as:

> Correct!
>
> fact: Len Wiseman and Kate Beckingsale, who plays Underworlds heroine,
> Selene, married 1 year after the release of Underworld.

Here is the code I have so far

```
questions = {
'Who directed Underworld, Underworld Evolution?': 'a'
}
for i in questions:
    print(i)
    ans = input("Enter your answer (a/b/c/d): ")
    if ans == questions[i]:
        print("Correct!")
        score = score + 10
        num_corr = num_corr + 1
    else:
        print("That is incorrect.")
        score = score + 0
        num_corr = num_corr + 0
print("You got ", num_corr, " of 10 correct.")
print("Your final score is: ",score)
```

How do I add the code to display the fact for each question from the dictionary of facts right after "Correct!"?

Comment: I don't quite understand what was the difficulty for you to add another `print()`.

Comment: Please add your dictionaries (with a few items each) to your code.

Comment: Why not printing the fact right after `Print("Correct!)`, and get the value of fact using `i` or some other key based on your `fact` dictionary ?

Comment: Sounds like a homework question. If you've written the code snippet above, it's pretty clear where you would add the fact displaying code. Otherwise please attempt to solve the problem yourself first and show where you've come up short.

Comment: Your `if ans == questions[i]:`  looks pretty strange to me.

Comment: can you post your 'dictionary for the answers and a dictionary for the facts' ?

Comment: You haven't shown us how you are storing these "facts", so we cannot tell you how to print them...

Comment: Very new to all of this (Python and Stack) so please bare with me.  Through your comments I have figured it all out, so thank you all for your help.  I realize that I should add as much of the code as possible to give you more of an idea of what I'm trying to do(the attempts I made to achieve what I was asking). I know this was probably more of a simple problem to solve but being new to this , it eluded me for a bit.  At the time of writing the question, I thought I had given enough information. Again, my apologies, but again thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a dictionary similar to this:

```py
questions = {
    'This is the Question. Any Questions?':'The answer (a)'
}
```

In your dictionary, you could have the value to be a list of answer and fact. It would look somethin like this:

```
questions = {
    'This is the Question. Any Questions?':['The answer(a)', 'This is a random fact']
}
for i in questions: 
    print(i) 
    ans = input("Enter your answer (a/b/c/d): ") 
    if ans == questions[i][0]: 
        print("Correct!")
        print(f'Heres a random fact: \n{questions[i][1]}') 
        score = score + 10 
        num_corr = num_corr + 1 
    else: 
        print("That is incorrect.") 
        score = score + 0 
        num_corr = num_corr + 0 
print("You got ", num_corr, " of 10 correct.") 
print("Your final score is: ",score)
```

Some other little tipps:

- you dont have to write "num_corr = num_corr + 1" instead you can use +=
- "num_corr + 0" is unnecessary
- since you always give a player 10 points for a correct answer, you can just keep track of the correct answers and multiply them by 10 in the end

Here's what that would look like:

```
all_questions = {
    'This is the Question. Any Questions?':['The answer(a)', 'This is a random fact']
}
for question in all_questions: 
    print(i) 
    ans = input("Enter your answer (a/b/c/d): ") 
    if ans == all_questions[question][0]: 
        print("Correct!")
        print(f'Heres a random fact: \n{all_questions[i][1]}') 
        num_corr = += 1 
    else: 
        print(f"That is incorrect. The correct answer was {all_questions[question][0]}") 
print(f"You got {num_corr} of {len(all_questions.keys())} correct.") 
print("Your final score is: ",num_corr*10)
```

I hope it helped :)

Comment: This did help!  Thank you for your patience and understanding even though this was probably a very simple problem to fix.  It is very much appreciated!  I am self-teaching python as well.